# vue refresh current page, but can't get the query params

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

vue force refresh the current page with Chrome, I can't get the query params which is Object
[image: detail desc]

Comment: Can you add the relevant code where you are trying to get URL query params.

Comment: like this: this.$route.query.xxx，xxx is Object。if the xxx is String Or Int， It's OK

Answer (score 0):

as @pcwang said in the commments, you need to use `this.$route.query.xxx` instead of `this.$route.params.xxx`, where xxx is the query parameter you want to fetch.